# Explaination Of Azure Storage Account - Total Request Chart

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage, azure-table-storage

Can someone please help me understand the mechanics of an Azure Storage Account and what is happening when certain "requests" are being made.

The requests are broken down into Blobs, Tables, Queues, and File Resources

My set up is that I have created an Azure Media Service, and in uploading the video files it has created 5 "Blobs". 1 for each video.

[image: Request Chart]

What is happening when there is a spike in a certain type of request?

What type of request is valid when the videos are actually being viewed?

Why would there be a spike of 100s of requests for the "blob"!?

Answer (score 1):

Every interaction with blobs, tables, queues and files is supported by an underlying REST API. So you're seeing api call frequency.

There's no real way to say, exactly, why you have spikes at specific times, but it's likely related to uploading or downloading content to/from blob storage. You also have spikes in table storage (and tables are used for logging/diagnostic information).

You can enable storage analytics (for blobs), to see the exact blobs being accessed, and when, if you want that level of detail (those settings are located in the storage account's settings blade).

By the way: The frequency you're showing is *extremely* low. Those request spikes are likely for multiple sequential block blob sequences in your video files. That type of transactional volume is inconsequential from a cost perspective as well (given that storage transactions run a penny per 300,000).

Comment: Thank you for replying - Yes the traffic at the moment is very low. I'm just testing the platform for a live site. Is it the "file" statistics that I should be interested if I want to know how many times a video has been watched / requested