# Azure Storage Total Requests High

Tags: azure, azure-storage

I have signed up for Azure Storage the other day. I noticed today when I went into the Azure portal that there are about 500 requests per hour to the table storage. The strange thing is that I'm not using Table Storage and my site isn't live at the moment. So what could possibly be making all these requests? Any ideas?

[image]

Comment: This has come up before, such as [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38185179/272109) which seems almost identical. I posted an answer there that (hopefully) helps you. Also: just FYI 500 requests / hour isn't high - that amount (about 350,000 monthly) would run you about... a penny.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, mystery solved. It turns out it's the actual Azure Portal that is generating the traffic. I originally thought it was the SDK somehow making the calls, but then I had the website turned off, and the portal open, and it continued making requests. Close portal for a while, no requests.

Answer (score 2):

Azure Storage has this feature called [`Storage Analytics`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/hh343270.aspx) which performs logging and provides metrics data for a storage account. This data gets stored in the same storage account under special tables (starting with `$` e.g. `$MetricsCapacityBlob`). By default some analytics data is collected and this is why you're seeing these requests.

One way to check the transactions is by exploring contents of `$logs` blob container. It will tell you in details from where the requests to your storage accounts are being originated.

Comment: I had a look in the Azure Portal, but there don't seem to be any items in there with a $ prefix. I can't find the $logs blob container. The portal says that I don't have any blob containers. I searched for "$" and "$logs" and it came back not found.

Comment: @JacobJoz All metrics data is stored in tables. Please see the section "How Metrics Are Stored" of the article [About Storage Analytics Metrics](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/azure/hh343258.aspx).

Comment: It looks like it's caused by the Azure Storage SDK. I have added the Nuget package to my solution, and configured the access key in the config. Now everytime I run the website, the requests go up. The interesting thing is that I don't actually call any methods for storage yet. But sure enough, when I stop the website, the requests stop as well.